# What are the adverse effects of having too many tables in a database?

Tags: database

Before I explain my question, I want to say that I know this kind of question has been asked on SO before, but my question is on a totally different scale, and the situation seems to be fundamentally different from what I've read on other people's questions.

Background:

I'm doing some work for a client who has a database containing **2505 tables**. These 2505 tables are made up of a few hundred WordPress instances' tables, so these tables don't need to talk to each other or anything. It could just as easily be 250 databases of 10 tables each instead of one database of 2505 tables.

What's more: this particular app is currently used in just one U.S. state, and the goal is for it to be used in all 50. So that presumably means there would ultimately be 2500 * 50 = 125,000 total tables. That strikes me as a sign of a suboptimal design, to put it lightly.

The problem is that the client's developer understands so little about databases (he doesn't know about normalization, foreign keys or unique constraints, for example) that it's a real challenge to explain why 2505 tables in a database is not good database design.

**How would you explain, to someone who doesn't know much about databases, that 2505 tables in a single database is a bad idea?** (I'm looking for specific, fact-based, irrefutable reasons.)

(By the way, I think the root of the problem is platform choice - WordPress is probably not the right tool for the job - but I want to tackle the database issue first.)

Comment: To be clear, the "someone who doesn't know much about databases" is not non-technical, just inexperienced with databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just test it and report the results of your test? Just clone the existing production data 50 times into new tables and run some traffic against it.

That is irrefutable, does not require simplifying metaphors and is not deceptive (like one of the other answers suggest).

Answer (score 2):

If the person does not understand databases, using specific technical arguments would probably not help much. It could be better to use something an ordinary person could (pretend to) understand, preferably in the presence of their boss (or send them an e-mail with Cc: to their boss).

The boss would probably react on saying that keeping many tables in one database in *unsafe*, or simply is not an *industry standard*. The resulting database would be *slow*, could possibly *crash*, and that could make the customers really angry.

This kind of communication is manipulative, but a straight technical talk will probably get you nowhere. If the developer understands nothing, and still insists on disagreeing with you, then speaking about good or bad design is useless (maybe even worse than useless -- noobs are sometimes proud of using bad design, because being able to work with bad design demonstrates their supposed leet skillz). You are going to convince the boss; so you must speak the language the boss understands. The boss wants to avoid a risk of project failure, and they would probably agree that using a *non-standard* technique increases the risk. Exact technical proofs are probably not necessary, expressing a strong certainty in what you are saying works better (which is generally sad, but in this specific case it works for you).

Comment: Ditto this. +1 for being real world.

Comment: This kind of manipulative crap is what I fight with every day. I really don't like such practices to be recommended here.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and tell him a database is like a cabinet with each table being a drawer.

Now have him imagine looking through the cabinet with 2505 or 125.000 drawers... To make it more challenging, he will have no ladder or other means of reaching the top drawers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to explain to a non-technical person why a database like that is bad you can't go into detail as many of us would.

Now, while it might (or not) be true you could use a some simple answers:

a) "If you have more tables, the commands(queries) to get the date are going to be too complex/big - meaning that your system won't be that responsive/fast/etc"

or

b) "If anything bad happens or you need to modify the database, you'll have to pay more since it's not optimized and whoever you pay to do it will have a harder time"

That's how I would explain it anyways.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Money.

Developers cost money. Maintenance costs money.

Have a meeting with a black board or send an e-mail with something like the following on it:

```
Developer Costs £500 per day

Creating the tables behind the application
-----------------------------------

Time to create 1 table = 20 minutes
Time to create 125,000 tables = 125,000 x 20 = 2,500,000 minutes
Cost to create 125,000 tables = 2,500,000 / 60 / 8 * 500 = £2,604,166


Updating the application
-----------------------------------

Time to update 1 table = 5 minutes
Time to update 125,000 tables = 125,000 * 5 = 625,000 minutes
Cost to update 125,000 tables = 625,000 / 60 / 8 * 500 = £651,041

Cost in 1st month
-----------------------------------
£654,041 + £2,604,166 = £3.258m
```

Translate into local currency, and point out that the "boss" will be saving this much cash on maintenance every time they want to change something. Just to ensure you don't get stuck doing this for nothing point out that this is an *extra* on top of normal procedures.

Comment: That is a good approach (although the numbers clearly level off when automation is added at a one-time cost).

Comment: @usr, automation = 60 minutes per table :-).